# detecting if the button onclick event is attached

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the button and i am trying to detect through jquery that if the button has a click event attached and has a specific message please hide it..

as of now i have nothing which comes up:

Here is the code i have:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="iuttons" onclick="alert('The number of pages in your results is too long for us to print.');"><img height="16" alt="Submit" src="mall.png" width="16" align="center"></button>
```

I am trying something like this: but not sure how:

```
$("#iuttons").on('submit').length() {
   hide the button [same button]
}else{
show the button 
}
```

This needs to be running on the doc ready so it can know what to do

Comment: Are you attaching the handler with onclick in HTML? In that case you can just get that attribute and check it. If you use other ways you got to check the onclick of the particular node. You should as well pen down your actual requirement so that we could suggest a better solution

Comment: the button has already an alert attached, i just want to checked if the `alert` is there in then hide the button else keep it displayed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but if you are trying to hide the button on click use this :

```
$('.iuttons').click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function hasClickEventAttached(id){
jQuery.each($('#' + id).data('events'), function (i, event) {

            jQuery.each(event, function (i, handler) {

                if(handler.type == 'click') return true;

            });

        });
     return false;
}
```

now you can use it like:

```
if(hasClickEventAttached('iuttons'))
      alert('onclick event is attached');
else
      alert('onclick event is not attached');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery < 1.8.3, you can use something simple like this:

```
// your element
var $el = $('.iuttons');

// set listener
$el.on('submit', function() { alert('hi'); });

// check events
var hasListener = !!($el.data('events') || {})['submit'];

// print to console
console.log( "Submit listener: ", hasListener );
```

---

Just throwing this in the mix since it's related; it's not a sufficient answer.

Chrome, Firefox, and Safari have built-in support for a function called `getEventListeners`. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject

```
getEventListeners(myElement);

// output: 
// Object {mouseover: Array[1]}
```

Comment: my issue lies where i still need to support the IE8. also, what i am checking is when it checks if the onclick has that text then hide the button else show the button